# Directive inside Directive call function not work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have 2 directives, one inside the other, the case is in the last directive I have the call to a "ng-click" function that is inside it, except that the function is not called. Could you explain how to solve this? And why is not it called? ...

**Calling the first directive, within it we have the call to the second directive "bg-teste-dois"**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    BgTeste.$inject = ['$log', '$compile'];

    angular.module('testeApp').directive('bgTeste', BgTeste);


    function BgTeste($log, $compile) {
        return {
            'restrict': 'E',
            'scope': {
            },
            'replace': true,


            'link': function (scope, element) {

                var builder, compiledElm;

                builder = {
                    'buildTemplate': function (scope, cb) {

                        var template;


                        template =  '<div>' +
                                        '<i class="material-icons" style="color: #fff; margin-top: 4px;">exit_to_app</i>' +

                                        '<bg-teste-dois></bg-teste-dois>' +

                                    '</div>';


                        cb(null, template);
                    }

                };


                builder.buildTemplate(scope, function (err, template) {

                    if (err) {
                        $log.warn(err);
                        return;
                    }

                    compiledElm = $compile(template)(scope);

                    if (builder.postCompile) {
                        builder.postCompile(compiledElm);
                    }

                    element.replaceWith(compiledElm);

                });
            }
        };
    }

}());
```

**Calling the second directive, in it I have the ng-click with the call to the function q is inside it:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    BgTesteDois.$inject = ['$log', '$compile'];

    angular.module('testeApp').directive('bgTesteDois', BgTesteDois);


    function BgTesteDois($log, $compile) {
        return {
            'restrict': 'E',
            'scope': {
            },
            'replace': true,


            'link': function (scope, element) {

                var builder, compiledElm;

                scope.acao = this.acao;

                builder = {
                    'buildTemplate': function (scope, cb) {

                        var template;


                        template =  '<div ng-click="acao()"></div>';


                        cb(null, template);
                    },

                    'acao' : function () {
                        console.log('Enter here.....');
                    }

                };


                builder.buildTemplate(scope, function (err, template) {

                    if (err) {
                        $log.warn(err);
                        return;
                    }

                    compiledElm = $compile(template)(scope);

                    if (builder.postCompile) {
                        builder.postCompile(compiledElm);
                    }

                    element.replaceWith(compiledElm);

                });
            }
        };
    }

}());
```

Comment: Not sure, but I think you should use a factory.
Knowledgeable staff can help.